# How to generate custom class name using maven archetype command mvn archetype:generate from old project

Tags: maven

1.I have created one archetype project which looks like this
   [Created Archetype Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlwbZ.png)
 2. Content of pom.xml present in target/generated-sources/archetype/pom.xml is 
   as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.7.RELEASE
         
    
    com.app
    maven-archetype-demo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    maven-archetype-demo
    Demo project on Maven Archetype

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

3. Now I have created new project using this archetype using command
   mvn archetype:generate 
        -DarchetypeGroupId=com.maven.app 
        -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-app-archetype 
        -DarchetypeVersion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 
        -DgroupId=com.app 
        -DartifactId=new-app 
        -DinteractiveMode=false
4. Folder Structure of Created New Project is as follow
   [New Project Struture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wcm.png)

I want to change java class name present in package com.app as it is taking same class name from old project at the time generating project

Comment: What have you tried already, what is the error you see? Please provide some additional context to your question.

Comment: @triplem-- Updated my question....please guide me further

Comment: Why don't you just rename the class?

Comment: I want it dynamic....thats why

Comment: And archetype creates just a starting point for your project. I do not really understand your point. After the generation, you can do whatever you like. And you do not need to use an archetype in the first place as well.

Comment: @triplem--I want to generate dynamic class name as project name for main application coz lets say I do have some 20 services (project) created from archetype so I do have to change class name for each and every project(service). If archetype is able to give dynamic class name so....is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why would you like to generate multiple services in the same project. There seems to be a mis-understanding here.